# What's the difference between R_386_GOT32 and R_386_GOT32X?

Tags: x86, elf, relocation

I've found a lot of documentation for `R_386_GOT32`, but not `R_386_GOT32X`. I was able to find https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/intel386-psABI-draft.pdf which shows the calculation for `R_386_GOT32X`, but it looks to be the same as that for `R_386_GOT32`

> R_386_GOT32  |  3 | word32 | G + A - GOT / G + A†
>
> R_386_GOT32X | 43 | word32 | G + A - GOT / G + A†

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both relocations have the same effect and the calculations are the same, but `R_386_GOT32X` relocations allow the linker to optimize the instructions used for the calculation, using immediate operands instead of memory operands under certain conditions.

H. J. Lu (Intel engineer who introduced `R_386_GOT32X`) [explains it](https://groups.google.com/g/ia32-abi/c/GbJJskkid4I) in the IA32 System V ABI mailing list:

> X86 instruction encoding supports converting some instructions on
> memory operand with GOT32 relocation against symbol, foo, into a
> different form on immediate operand if foo is defined locally. Those
> instructions are:
>
> ```
> call *foo@GOT[(%reg)]       => nop call foo or call foo nop
> jmp *foo@GOT[(%reg)]        => jmp foo nop 
> mov foo@GOT[(%reg1)], %reg2 => lea foo[@GOTOFF(%reg1)], %reg2
> ```
>
> When osition-independent code is disable,
>
> ```
> test %reg1, foo@GOT[(%reg2)] => test $foo, %reg1 binop
> foo@GOT[(%reg1)], %reg2      => binop $foo, %reg2
> ```
>
> where binop is one of adc, add, and, cmp, or, sbb, sub, xor
> instructions.
>
> I am proposing to add a new relocation, R_386_GOT32X, to i386 psABI.
> Instead of generating R_386_GOT32 relocation agasint foo for
> foo@GOT(%reg), we generate R_386_GOT32X. R_386_GOT32X relocation can
> also be used without the base register for the global offset table,
> foo@GOT, when position-independent code is disable. In this case, the
> static base address of the global offset table will be used instead.
> Linker can treat R_386_GOT32X the same as R_386_GOT32 or it can
> perform the transformations listed above.

Indeed, according to the  IA32 System V ABI document you linked (section A.2):

> ### Optimize R_386_GOT32X Relocation
>
> The Intel386 instruction encoding supports converting certain
> instructions on memory operand with `R_386_GOT32X` relocation against
> symbol, `foo`, into a different form on immediate operand if `foo` is
> defined locally:
>
> **Convert call, jmp and mov** Convert memory operand
> of `call`, `jmp` and `mov` into immediate operand.
>
> | Memory Operand | Immediate Operand |
> | --- | --- |
> | `call *foo@GOT(%reg)` | `nop call foo` |
> | `call *foo@GOT(%reg)` | `call foo nop` |
> | `jmp *foo@GOT(%reg)` | `jmp foo nop` |
> | `mov foo@GOT(%reg1), %reg2` | `lea foo@GOTOFF(%reg1), %reg2` |
>
> **Convert Test and Binop** Convert memory operand of `call`, `jmp`, `mov`, `test`
> and `binop` into immediate operand, where `binop` is one of `adc`, `add`,
> `and`, `cmp`, `or`, `sbb`, `sub`, `xor` instructions, when position-independent
> code is disabled.
>
> | Memory Operand | Immediate Operand |
> | --- | --- |
> | `call *foo@GOT` | `nop call foo` |
> | `call *foo@GOT` | `call foo nop` |
> | `jmp *foo@GOT` | `jmp foo nop` |
> | `mov foo@GOT, %reg` | `mov $foo, %reg` |
> | `test %reg, foo@GOT` | `test $foo, %reg` |
> | `binop foo@GOT, %reg` | `binop $foo, %reg` |
> | `call *foo@GOT(%reg)` | `nop call foo` |
> | `call *foo@GOT(%reg)` | `call foo nop` |
> | `jmp *foo@GOT(%reg)` | `jmp foo nop` |
> | `mov foo@GOT(%reg1), %reg2` | `mov $foo, %reg2` |
> | `test %reg1, name@GOT(%reg2)` | `test $foo, %reg1` |
> | `binop name@GOT(%reg1), %reg2` | `binop $foo, %reg2` |

Comment: Ahh thank you. I saw that section but I didn't know that was *the* purpose of GOT32X.